# Iphone not receiving .ics calendar

Tags: asp.net

can anybody tell why this text does not come as an attachement to my iphone it works for Android and its a calendar event i click on it to add it to my calendar

here what it looks like on the iphone when i get the email

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
ProdId:-//Mycompany Calendar//ttw
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:REQUEST
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20120812T090000Z
DTEND:20120813T160000Z
LOCATION;ENCODING=QUOTED-PRINTABLE:location mine
DESCRIPTION;ENCODING=QUOTED-PRINTABLE:my description
SUMMARY;ENCODING=QUOTED-PRINTABLE:
UID;ENCODING=QUOTED-PRINTABLE:580e0a63-2009-4373-8743-6afdce1f7012
TRIGGER:-PT15M
PRIORITY:3
ORGANIZER:donotreply@Mycompany.com
SEQUENCE:1
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it turned out that there was a method used in the write procedure where we used writeline instead of write because the writeline always added a new line and the iphone device did not know how to handle it.